# What is the (searchable) name for this syntax...?

Tags: c++, c++11

```
typedef std::function<bool(int)> MyFunction;
```

That `bool(int)` template argument notation syntax - does it have a name? I tried to read C++ standard about this syntax and did not know what to search for.

Obviously, using it in other contexts seems to fail.

```
typedef bool(int) MyFunctionType; // does not work.
```

So I assume there is a special chapter about this syntax somewhere...

Thanks.

Comment: Even though it does not refer to the grammar, I'd associate the term "function type" with something like `bool(int)`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know of a common name for this. In the standard, it's called a *type-id*, after its grammar production.

The *type-id* `bool(int)` names the type "function of `(int)` returning `bool`".

It doesn't work with `typedef` (which uses the normal declaration syntax instead), but alias declared with `using` does use a *type-id*:

```
using MyFunctionType = bool(int);
```

Comment: but but ... The only definition in C++ for <type-id> is in the formal grammar. And in the formal grammar there is no production involving '(' and ')'. Now I am confused. Hidden grammar feature or sunday-blindness?

Comment: Ah I found it - 'parameters-and-qualfiers' is the production.

Comment: It does work with `typedef`: `typedef bool MyFunctionType(int);`

Comment: On which compiler? @T.C. is right - the standard says ``using`` uses a type-id. And ``typedef`` does not. But it works anyway. Lol - I am amused. I tried the ``typedef bool (*MyFunctionType)(int);`` But that was obviously not correct.

Comment: @user2225104 You didn't form the `typedef` correctly.

Comment: @user2225104 `typedef bool (*MyFunctionType)(int);` is the `typedef` for a function pointer (`bool (*)(int)`), not a function type (`bool(int)`)

Comment: @0x499602D2 There's no *type-id* in `typedef bool MyFunctionType(int);`.

Comment: That's not my point, I'm just addressing how he would correctly form the `typedef` syntax. It's now clear that when you say "it doesn't work with `typedef`" you're referring  to it being used with a type-id.

Comment: `template<class X>using t=X; typedef t<bool(int)> SeeItWorks;` ;)

Answer (score 2):

N4140 calls `bool(int)` a *function type* in [dcl.fct]. As stated in the other answer, this is a *type-id*:

> [dcl.name]/1 To specify type conversions explicitly, and as an
>   argument of `sizeof`, `alignof`, `new`, or `typeid`, the name of a
>   type shall be specified. This can be done with a *type-id*, which is
>   syntactically a declaration for a variable or function of that type
>   that omits the name of the entity.